# info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason ‘1007’

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, vectorization, c11, sse2

I am trying out the Auto-Vectorizer mode of Visual Studio 2013 on x86_64, and I am a bit surprised with the following. Consider the naive code:

```
static void rescale( double * __restrict out, unsigned short * __restrict in, size_t n, const double intercept, const double slope )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        out[i] = slope * in[i] + intercept;
}
```

Visual Studio returns that it is failing on such naive example with:

```
--- Analyzing function: rescale
c:\users\malat\autovec\vec.c(18) : info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason '1007'
```

Where compilation line is (I am only interested in SSE2 for now):

```
cl vec.c /O2 /Qpar /Qpar-report:2
```

Looking at the documentation:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235(v=vs.120).aspx

Leads to:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585(v=vs.120).aspx#BKMK_ReasonCode100x

Which reads as:

> The loop induction variable or the loop bounds are not signed 32-bit
>   numbers (int or long). Resolve this by changing the type of the
>   induction variable.

Is there a way to rewrite this loop so that the Auto-Vectorizer mode is triggered properly ?

I failed to rewrite the code using a simple approach:

```
static void rescale( double * __restrict out, unsigned short * __restrict in, size_t n, const double intercept, const double slope )
{
  const long first = (long)n;
  const long secnd = n > LONG_MAX ? n - LONG_MAX : 0;
  for( long i = 0; i < first; ++i )
    out[i] = slope * in[i] + intercept;
  for( long i = 0; i < secnd; ++i )
    out[LONG_MAX+i] = slope * in[LONG_MAX+i] + intercept;
}
```

In the above case Visual Studio now reports:

```
--- Analyzing function: rescale
c:\users\malat\autovec\vec.c(21) : info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason '1000'
c:\users\malat\autovec\vec.c(23) : info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason '1000'
```

Which means:

> The compiler detected a data dependency in the loop body.

I cannot see where there would be a data dependency in my second case.

How should I rewrite my initial code to please the Auto-Vectorizer mode of Visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither SSE2 nor its predecessor, SSE, have proper instructions that convert `uint16_t`-s into `double`-s.

Convert `in` into `double*`.

Comment: `gcc` seems to produce something much faster. I need to dig exactly what it is doing, but yes you are right my `in` expressed as `unsigned short` may not be trivial to use directly from SSE2.

Comment: @malat, AFAIR, GCC can construct vectors «by hand», filling multiple XMM registers and then unrolling several iterations to make use of them.